# Does Node.js Request node store HTTPOnly cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, httpcookie, cookiejar

I would like to store the cookies that I receive in a HTTP response and send them to the server in the next HTTP request. I know that HTTPOnly cookies "dont like" JS. So does the Request node (using node.js) store the HTTPOnly cookies in jar if set to true?

If not how can I work around this, since this is what keeps the session open.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are returned as a part of response headers for most of the HTTP requests made. So if you happen to use request module to make your HTTP requests, you can console log response and check for the cookies in headers. Thereafter you can use them for your own manipulations and working. You can do something like below:

```
request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers:<some-req-headers>
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
       console.log(err);
 } else {
       console.log(response.headers);
   }
});
```

Mostly cookies are part of 'set-cookie' field of response.headers as far as I have observed.